# Invisible notes (to the audience) in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer

Since I'm about to have a conference talk, I was wondering if there is a way to write notes on the slides that will only be seen by me. To be more precise, on the projector there would be my slides full screen, and on my laptop I would see my slides and some notes.

I tried with the following:

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right} % Both
\setbeamertemplate{note page 
{\pagecolor{yellow!5}\insertnote}\usepackage{palatino}
```

obtaining with the code

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Attempt}
   Hello! \note[item]{My speaker note}
\end{frame}
```

the following output:

[image]

I don't have a projector to prove and try if this solution works. I mean, can I save this presentation on a pdf file and project it? Is it sufficient? Or are there other steps to do with Adobe Acrobat reader, for example?

Thanks a lot for your help !!

Comment: See [Section 22 of the Beamer manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#page=217). It's something pretty specific (involving your PDF viewer displaying a wide document that spans multiple screens, and your multiple screens being set up in a specific way) that you should IMO test with the exact projector and operating system / PDF viewer that you'll be using at the conference (and have a backup plan in case things don't work). For example, the manual points out that it won't work if you're using Adobe Acrobat Reader on macOS.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, thank you!

Comment: Closed because it has been answered and that was the solution, though the answerer chose to do it via a comment. Can be re-opened if the answerer would like to change that comment into an answer.